# Invalid identifier error: SQL code in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am testing this code in Toad, Oracle. It is giving me an error "end : an invalid identifier". Can someone please help me to figure out where i am going wrong.?

```
SELECT 
      NVL(PACE_HR.F_GET_INSTR_CRHRS(18,
         case
           when to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'MM') >= 09
             then to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')||'70'
               else to_char(to_number(to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')) - 1) || '70'
                end),0) 
       as fall_instr_crhrs,
       nvl(pace_hr.f_get_non_instr_crhrs(18,
         case
           when to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'MM') >= 09
             then to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')||'70'
               else to_char(to_number(to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')) - 1) || '70'
                 end),0),
       end as fall_non_instr_crhrs

FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 2):

What is this line doing?

```
  end as fall_non_instr_crhrs
```

Try:

```
SELECT 
  NVL(PACE_HR.F_GET_INSTR_CRHRS(18,
     case
       when to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'MM') >= 09
         then to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')||'70'
           else to_char(to_number(to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')) - 1) || '70'
            end),0) 
   as fall_instr_crhrs,
   nvl(pace_hr.f_get_non_instr_crhrs(18,
     case
       when to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'MM') >= 09
         then to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')||'70'
           else to_char(to_number(to_char(to_date(&&payroll_date),'YYYY')) - 1) || '70'
             end),0) as fall_non_instr_crhrs
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Yep, just remove the end, he can keep the alias

Comment: @CodeBird and the comma before the `end`.

Comment: GOOD eye! Missed that